# Trying to compile this C++ file on my student server for school

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

> Now we are going to compile the file with the GNU C++ compiler. We
>   call the compiler with `g++`. So issue the command `g++ Lab4.cpp`. Now do
>   an `ls` and what do you get?

When I issue this command, I get this.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using terminal in OS X.

This is my professor's code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/*Start of Program*/
/*Control*/
int main ()
{
    /*Variable Definition*/
    int iNum1;  //names the storage area for user entered value
    int iNum2;  //names the storage area for the second user entered value
    int iResult;    //names the storage area for a computed value

    /*Screen Output is done with a cout*/
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    cout << "My name is Burak Ersoy, I am learning to program in C++" << endl;

    /*Read*/
    cout << "Enter your 1st number: ";  //prompts user to enter a number
    cin >> iNum1;   //stores the user entered value in iNum1
    cout << "The number you entered is " << iNum1 << endl; //shows user what they entered

    cout << "Enter your 2nd number: ";  //asks user for another value
    cin >> iNum2;   //stores the second user entered value in iNum2
    cout << "The second number you entered is " << iNum2 << endl;

    /*Calc*/
    iResult = iNum1 / iNum2;    //computes division using iNum1 and iNum2

    /*Print*/
    cout << "When I divide " << iNum1 << " by " << iNum2 <<
        " the result is " << iResult << " with a remainder of "
        << iNum1 % iNum2 << endl;
    /*Outputs the entire process and result of the computation to screen*/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks as if you are using the terminal on OS X to connect to a RedHat Linux 'student server' at school.  What's in `Lab4.cpp`?  Is there an `int main()` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)` in it?

Comment: Given that code, I conclude you mistyped the command line.  Please show exactly what you typed — or review what you typed.  The error message is consistent with what you'd get from compiling an empty file.  For example, on Mac OS X, compiling an empty file, I got: `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status` which is different in detail from your error message, but closely related.

Comment: Yeah there is int main () in it

Comment: So I see.  Any chance you have an empty file `lab4.cpp` and you typed `g++ lab4.cpp` instead of `g++ Lab4.cpp`?  On a Mac, the files are the same (HFS is case-insensitive by default); Linux has case-sensitive file systems.  (Or, conversely, did you copy the file to `lab4.cpp` but you have an empty `Lab4.cpp` and correctly typed `g++ Lab4.cpp`?)

Comment: I typed this    g++ Lab4.cpp

Comment: @NathanSchroeder Is that the code you see if you `cat Lab4.cpp` in the terminal?

Comment: Ok I think the problem is i somehow transfered the cpp file from my local machine to the remote machine but the wrong way i guess i transfered and empty file? How would i transfer a .cpp file to the remote machine(student server)

Comment: `ftp` or `scp` or …  From another window on your Mac, `scp Lab4.cpp student-server.example.edu:` should do it if you have secure connections set up; the file would be in your home directory on the student server machine.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like you're compiling code that doesn't define main. You'll need to either adjust the code (maybe you spelled main wrong, or forgot to define it), or compile the code into an object file that's not an executable (at your level, that's not likely to be what you want).

Here's a minimal C/C++ program (I'm not claiming it matches every spec) and what should happen when you compile and run it:

```
$ echo 'int main(){}' > foo.cpp
$ g++ foo.cpp -ofoo
$ ./foo
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: post the code so we can see what might be wrong. It could be a typo somewhere, or a transcription problem. I assume you invoked g++ just as described, so that part is already known.